# Why am I getting an unsatisfiable error when trying to install pypyodbc using conda?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install the pypyodbc package, but I'm running into an error:

```
(base) C:\>conda install -c zegami pypyodbc
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports.functools_lru_cache
  - pypyodbc
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I don't understand what the problem is here, or why backports.functools_lru_cache would have any impact. I've also tried different pypyodbc contributions, including one from CIT and mbonix.  The specific package causing the error in each case is different (urllib3 and futures, respectively), but the result is the same.  In any event, here is the output from conda info. I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Thanks,
Brad

```
(base) C:\>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\braddavi\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\braddavi\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 2.7.15.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs
                          C:\Users\braddavi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs
                          C:\Users\braddavi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\braddavi\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.15 Windows/201
2ServerR2 Windows/6.3.9600
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


(base) C:\>
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to track this down recursively. First, do `conda info pypyobdc` (possibly including any channels) and write down all the dependencies and their versions. Then, do the same for `backports.functools_lru_cache`, then the same for each of it's dependencies, and for each of those dependencies, and so on. Usually you'll find the conflict pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I really appreciate it.  I'll do that and then report back!